# How to Stop VS Designer from messing up my already present code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Everytime I move to Designer View my whole designer.cs code is messed up :
VS Designer reorganizes code blocks and puts an irritant verbose prefixes like "`this.whatever`"
and fully qualifies objects using "`System.Windows.Forms.whatever`"
I Know that "Designer.cs" is not intended to be edited but I need to do some GUI code customization from time to time and would like these to stay as I changed them.

How to avoid that ? (Guess this is too funky for VS to handle)

(Actually I am just avoiding the use of the designer and do it all by hand, the good old way)

**Update :** 
*I am surprised to see the herd-like reaction towards this question. Sorry if it is disturbing, but it is interesting to see that, before hitting me on the hand saying "DON'T DO that, it's Bad", NO ONE asked WHY I wanted to do it.
 IMHO the question is relevant and that's why : Many of the "auto-generated" code is rubbish and of absolutely no use, it does need some enhancement. One example (among soooo many others) : Why generate a Size/Location property when the control's Dock Mode is set to Fill ? I wanted to take advantage of the benefits whithout the drawdowns. 
Anyway, I'll keep the short answer : You take it ALL (with the rubbish) or leave it ALL.*

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? I think earlier versions (I think VS2003 did this) did not use partial classes like newer versions - they modified some kind of "header" region in the same file.

Comment: 2010 :-) Yes before partial classes that was hell indeed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simple: **don't edit the designer code.**  Those warnings are there for a reason, and for Visual Studio to work correctly it needs to *own* that file.

This is a partial class: everything you need to do, you can do in the matching non-designer file for that class; this includes all your control declarations and other things.  Since you're trying to avoid the designer entirely, let visual studio have that file and just put everything in your normal .cs file.

**Update:** 
Based on the comment, I want to add the following —
Either use the designer or don't use the designer.  Don't be wishy-washy about it.  If you're using and relying on the designer for some things, you ***MUST*** leave the designer's file alone.

If you're avoiding the designer, then really avoid the designer.  *Everything* it does you can do in your own code (except of course for the visual queues, but even that can be done better via prototyping).  You can even create your own additional file for the partial class to keep designer-like code in.

If you're only using the designer as an occasional code generator to help reduce some boring typing, do that in a separate project or on a throw-away form in your existing project and just copy/paste the code over.

Comment: I Need/Want to edit the designer code. Simply because not ALL properties are editable via the Designer. Putting personal code outside the designer.cs code will create at least 2 problems : 1 -  all my GUI code will not be present in the same file, 2 - The designer will ignore and not show any component that is on my extra-control declaration file (outside designer.cs)

Comment: If a control is not declared in the designer.cs file, I doubt it will be usable from the designer view, so putting the code outside that file and not being able to edit it visually, or putting it in that file and messing my GUI code customization comes down to the same thing.

Comment: @Mika - the key word in your comment is `edit it visually`.  If you want to do that, you can't edit the designer file yourself.  **End of story**.  You're alternatives are to not edit things visually at all or to put your edits in another location.

Comment: Ok, Ok, Got it, fair enough... I prefer to have full control of my code and I use the designer occasionally. I was already doing the throw-away form workaround. Just wondered if there was a cleaner way to do it. COuld'nt help asking/negociating, it's in my genes :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped you gain 10 Points to add to your 89.1k collection :-)  See my update. Case closed. Thanx anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The designer should only be writing code in `FormName.Designer.cs` *which you should not touch*. Visual Stuiod declares a partial class implemented in two files - one for the designer, and one for your code. I'd be surprised to hear that the designer was rewriting the non-designer file.

If this doesn't help. please give more details of which version of VS you're using, which files are being rewritten, and which bits of those files.

Comment: I already know all that. I have not precised that what I want is to be able to use the Designer while keeping the code on the designer.cs  "as is", after I manually edit it. Probably this is a too funky use case for VS.

Comment: @Mika: No, you can't do that. You don't own the .Designer.cs file - the designer does. You shouldn't be changing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always extend the designer class by putting your custom code in another cs file. The designer can't touch that and the compiler will compile your additions to that class. If you're doing something like adding properties or methods its super to simple to do:

```
// MyWinformExtension.cs
partial class MyWinformName
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public void ProcessData()
    {
        // do some processing..
    }
}
```

Voila! That's how you add your own code. You can't alter the designer code because it will be re-written ALL DAY LONG by the IDE. That's why there are warnings in the source and why everyone else is telling you the same thing.

Comment: AHA. I knew there SHOULD have been some cleaner way to do that. I know my request is highly Unorthodox and funky. But I always want to have my cake AND eat it :-)

Comment: I don't think it's an unorthodox question. when we're developing winforms I think its natural for us to want to have control over all the source in our project that VS makes available. That's why there are warnings and why your Winform classes are partial so you can extend the functionality yourself.